# How to determine the port that minikube is running it's ssh service on

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to determine the port that Minikube randomly selects to run its ssh service for connecting to it.

I have been able to view that information from Docker Desktop by looking at the entry for Minikube but recently it has stopped showing. After I run `minikube tunnel` and do `ps aux | grep ssh` I can see where minikube has specified the randomly selected port for use in setting up tunnels. I am wondering how I can view this information directly from Minikube or k8s without jumping through hoops to discover it.

Comment: SO is fior programming questions

Comment: @Vega Not sure I agree. Where do you suggest someone should post this question if not SO? I've seen SO used for more than just programming questions actually.

Comment: Such use is *ab*use, if you see it. SO is in fact a site for questions about programming or programming tools. As for where to ask, ServerFault or Webmasters would be the sites for Kubernetes questions not involving programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can by inspecting whatever is in the `~/.minikube` directory.

Take a look below:

- `cat ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/config.json | grep -i SSH`

```json
        "SSHUser": "docker",
        "SSHPort": 62415,
        "SSHKeyPath": "",
```

You can find there also SSH keys:

- `ls -1 ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/ | grep id_rsa`

```bash
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
```